# Invalid date hides form button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am having a problem where I have a date picker form. I have found an error where if I enter an invalid date for both forms it hides the "submit" button I have. How can I make the forms dynamic so that they move left as well. The end goal is that my "submit" button will not be hidden. Here are the 2 screenshots of before and after 2 invalid dates (completely hidden submit button).

[no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8863.png)

[errors. and submit button is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL37P.png)

Heres's the code I have so far:

```
<div class="date-picker text-center x-small-heading">
  <%= form_tag '', method: :get, enforce_utf8: false do %>
      <%= label_tag 'start_date', t('date_picker.from'), class: 'x-small-heading' %>

        datetime_picker(datepicker: { value: @date_range.begin.strftime(ApplicationController::DATE_PICKER_DATE_FORMAT),
                                      start_date: date_picker_min.strftime(ApplicationController::DATE_PICKER_DATE_FORMAT),
                                      end_date: date_picker_max.strftime(ApplicationController::DATE_PICKER_DATE_FORMAT),
                                      name: 'start_date' })
    %>

    <%= label_tag 'end_date', t('date_picker.to'), class: 'x-small-heading' %>
    <%= datetime_picker(datepicker: { value: @date_range.end.strftime(ApplicationController::DATE_PICKER_DATE_FORMAT),
                                      start_date: date_picker_min.strftime(ApplicationController::DATE_PICKER_DATE_FORMAT),
                                      end_date: date_picker_max.strftime(ApplicationController::DATE_PICKER_DATE_FORMAT),
                                      name: 'end_date' })
    %>
    <%= submit_tag t('date_picker.submit'), name:nil %>
  <% end %>
  <% if defined?(show_quick_picks) && show_quick_picks %>
    <%= select_tag 'quick-picks', options_for_select(date_quick_pick_options(quick_picks_type)), include_blank: t('quick_picks.title') %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What languages are you using? ASP?.... CSS and Froms is not your answer, try adding tags that go along with your question

Comment: Those screenshots you mention would be helpful

Comment: Inserted screenshots, @MarkRawlingson and I am using Ruby on Rails, so utilizing CSS with that.

Comment: @JohnSmith Is the submit button just simply not being moved off the page due to the length of the validation messages? This is more of a design issue than a technical one. Either make the error messages shorter or move the submit button to a new line.

Comment: @benni_mac_b I'd like to keep the submit button on the same line. Is there a way to dynamically move them to the left so they are not blocking the submit button?

Comment: @JohnSmith What would you like to move to the left the form inputs themselves of just the validation messages?

Comment: @benni_mac_b the form inputs

Comment: I'm not understanding how you're envisioning moving the inputs to the left. They are already on the left. Do you mean you want to move them onto their own lines when there is an error so the submit button doesn't get pushed out of the way?

Comment: @MarkRawlingson That is precisely what I would like to do. Do you have any ideas how I would be able to do that?